# Turning on the internet data packets in android

Tags: android

**what i am doing**::

- I have disabled the `datapackets` so i don't have a internet connection
  at the moment in emulator
- Now i am checking whether the `internet connection` is available if not
  availabe i am using this code below to launch the screen so that i
  can enable the datapackets

*code*::`startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));`

**This code takes me to page**::

When i click on button it shows turning `wifion....` but it is not switching on no matter how long i wait

[image]

But **`when i close the app and go to settings manually. I can turn it on`**

**The permissions i have used are below::**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

---

*What is that i am doing wrong here ? how can i correct myself* !

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code.it might helps you

  Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);  
        startActivityForResult(gpsOptionsIntent,0); 

 if you are using wifiManager than you will need this permission.

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```